# drupal 8 querying all entitys of a type i just made

Tags: drupal, entity

I just made an entity 'car'

I have added 10 of these entities in the drupal cms.

Now i want all ID's of the entitys 'car' in my controller

This is what i tried so far that did not work:

```
    $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('car');
    $query->condition('status', 1);
    $ids = $query->execute(); 

    $entity_query = \Drupal::service('entity.query')->get('car');
    $uids = $entity_query->execute();
```

Both give me much more then just the 'car' entity.
they deliver other content types as well

Can someone help me how i can get all published 'car' nodes (id's)
so i can get all info for them with the load() command?

tnx

Comment: I found the solution for my problem: You need to get an instance of the entity, then use that to get the form. $entity = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('car')->create(array()); and then build form: $form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity,'addnew'); If you read this: hope it did help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

Create an instance of the entity.
Then use that instance to build the entityForm

$entity = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('car')->create(array());

$form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity,'default');

(I did create the entity using the drupal console and the default form you can set in the annotation section form in the entity file)